# Can Anyone See Anything Wrong With This Event Tracking Code?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am trying to track an event in a landing page creator called Unbounce. Do you see anything wrong with the code I've added? The element #lp-code-134 is a custom HTML element that a PayPal button has been added to.

`
$( '#lp-code-134' ).click( function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Buy', 'Submit', 'Buy Button Clicked', '30']);

});
`

Answer (score 0):

The event value is an integer, not a string - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Values

So if you're passing 30 as the event value, the event should look like this:

```
$('#lp-code-134').click(function() { 
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Buy', 'Submit', 'Buy Button Clicked', 30]);
});
```